# Ricochet tor version is out of date

Tags: configuration, update, tor-install, chat, ricochet

At this point the tor binary is in version 0.2.8.7.1. Ricochet (https://ricochet.im) hasn't been updated since February and is using tor version 0.2.7.6. There are some major updates between versions. Is it ever a good idea to simply copy the 2.8 binary provided by the official tor repo and overwrite the ricochet binary? I'm not clear on the security/functionality risks involved. Needless to say, I haven't tried this yet.

Comment: Orbot is also out of date, but nobody bothered to do anything about that.

Comment: 0.2.7.6 is still within the recommended set, it's not broken. This isn't an issue.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a question.

Comment: @canonizingironize the question is: "Is it a good idea to simply overwrite the ricochet binary?"

Comment: @canonizingironize it's a clear-stated question, so closing it is a pure vandalism

Answer (score 1):

The [list of recommended versions](https://consensus-health.torproject.org/#recommendedversions) contains 0.2.7.6, so it is not officially outdated.

If you want to use a newer version of Tor with Ricochet, just copy or link the Tor binary to the directory where Ricochet lives and start the software. Below you see a screenshot of Ricochet's settings which tells you that it runs with Tor version 0.2.8.8. I used the method above to get a newer version of Tor.

[image: version 0.2.8.8 of Tor]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can make a drop-in replacement of the binary files, as far as I know Tor is just bundled into the Ricochet, it's not patched and/or tailored in source to fit the needs

UPDATE: Take a look at it's [source code](https://github.com/ricochet-im/ricochet) - there's no shipped or included tor binary. There's only a messenger itself

Comment: Yes but the [releases that are shipped](https://ricochet.im/releases/1.1.2/) contained a `tor` binary.

Comment: indeed! the *release bundle* is obliged to deliver all the parts of the chain, and it's totally OK! Because it's a *bundle*